# Why doesn't "J'y ai lu un article" mean "J'ai lu un article sur cela"?

Tags: pronoms

If "y" means "sur cela" (or "dans cela"), **why doesn't "J'y ai lu un article" mean "J'ai lu un article sur cela"?** What's the logic?

(I know that "J'ai lu un article dessus" is what one might be looking for)

What other unexpected limitations does "y" have (if there are any on your mind)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Y* can either refer to a locative adjuncts, which can appear with a large set of prepositions, or to a subset of verb complements marked by the preposition *à*.

In a sentence like "J'ai lu un article sur le foot", "sur le foot" is indeed an adjunct but it has no locative function. And while it's a prepositional phrase, it doesn't use the right preposition (*sur* instead of *à*).

Thence, *y* can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the *y* denotes a complement of the **verb** *lire*, rather than a complement of the noun *article* (which would be "*sur cela*"). So it means *dans cela* as you noted.

I think this is a general rule: think of that *y* in relation to the **verbal group** rather than another element of the sentence.

Answer (score -3):

**I**

— square brackets in the reference blow : user LPH's additions
— the text of the reference below has been abbreviated.

> (**LBU § 675**) **Généralités** Les pronoms conjoints *en* et *y* tiennent la place d'un syntagme nominal prépositionnel. Ils peuvent avoir la fonction de compléments adverbiaux, tout en gardant leur valeur de représentants.
> A cause de cela, à cause de leur étymologie aussi on les appelle souvent adverbes pronominaux ou pronoms adverbiaux.

> (**LBU § 677**) **Fonctions de y**.
> a) Complément d'objet indirect d'un verbe.
> *Y* correspond à un syntagme nominal introduit par *à* :
> • Voici une lettre, vous Y répondrez.   [**répondre à**]
> • Le mal est grave : peut-on Y remédier ?  [**remédier à**]
> b) Complément adverbial d'un verbe. *Y* correspond à des syntagmes nominaux introduits par diverses prépositions, la préposition n'étant pas nécessairement présente auprès du nom antécédent. Il s'agit ordinairement de lieu :
> • Quelle grande maison ! on Y vit à l'aise. [**vivre dans une maison/ville/pays/etc**]
> • Il a un beau jardin ; il Y cultive des légumes. [**cultiver qqc dans un jardin/champs/serre/etc**]
> Par analogie avec des compléments de lieu, la préposition sous-jacente
> étant *sur* ou *dans*
> • Ce sont là des réflexions que le lecteur n'aime pas faire. Permettez-moi d'Y insister cependant. [**insister sur qqc** (le fait que le lecteur n'aime pas faire les réflexions en question)]
> • Pour ce qui est de mon silence, tu peux Y compter [**compter sur qqc** (son silence, c'est à dire qu'il se taira)]
> c) Complément d'un adjectif attribut.
> *Y* est placé devant le verbe copule
> •  La défiance ? Je n'Y suis pas enclin. [**enclin à qqc**]
> d) Attribut.
> Lorsque l'attribut affecte la forme d'un syntagme prépositionnel (et
> surtout lorsqu'il a une valeur plus ou moins locative), il est parfois repré-
> senté par *y*
> • Elle est en grand deuil.'... Mais Rose n'Y est pas

The case that applies is "b)". "Lire qqc dans qqc" means "to read something in sth", and "lire qqc sur qqc" means "to read sth on sth", but not in all cases.

For a book you can use only "dans";  "sur" is rare nowadays but it is still found in 19th century French. ([lu dans ce livre](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lu+dans+ce+livre%2Clu+sur+ce+livre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3))

- J'ai lu cet article dans/sur le livre rouge.  / J'ai lu cet article dans/sur ce livre.

For papers you use  "dans" but "sur" is correct as it is still used by some people; however, it is probably safer to use « dans » if you do not want to risk irritating your listener or you reader.

- J'ai lu cet article dans/sur le journal du soir.  /  J'ai lu cet article dans/sur ce journal. J'y ai lu cet article.

For a notice board there is only one choice, "sur".

- J'ai lu ce nom sur un écriteau. - / J'ai lu ce nom dessus. J'y ai lu ce nom.

"J'ai lu ce nom sur cela" can only be used if the notice board is first being specified (because "cela" is a demonstrative); the demonstrative has to be modified though (example below).

- — J'ai lu ce nom sur un écriteau.
  — Vous voulez dire l'écriteau illisible à l'entrée du magasin ?
  — Oui, je l'ai lu là-dessus. (Oui, j'y ai lu ce nom. — Oui, j'ai lu ce nom dessus.)

**II**

Do not confuse this with "J'ai lu un article dessus", which has nothing to do with "y". This means "I read an article about it.".

- — Tu as entendu parler de ce nouveau sport ?
  — Oui, j'ai lu un article dessus.

[lire qqc dessus](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22lu%20un%20article%20dessus%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147752/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-why-doesnt-jy-ai-lu-un-article-mean-jai-lu-un); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.